MassTransit - RabbitMQ - Separate Producers and Consumers
We have a strange behaviour in our app.
There's one queue UserUpdate containing commands, requiring an update of a user in our database.
Once this is done, we publish a message UserUpdated to all the process, so every process can clear his inmemory cache.
When we start the Consumer of the `UserUpdate' queue, RabbitMQ slow down instantly, 100% CPU, throughput on other queues is divided by 10. If we stop the consumer, RabbitMQ is fine again.
This is the only queue we see this behaviour, and it is not the first case where we get commands and produce events.
Searching what could cause this, I remembered reading that MassTransit should use two different bus instance in the app : 1 for the producers, 1 for the consumers.
But I can't find it in the MassTransit documentation.
Is it still the case ? Could it help us ?
May be I am wrong and it was never been written in the documentation also ?
If it is still something that we should do, what could be the best way to do it ? Using two Contacts : IProducerBus and IConsumerBus and use multibus ?

There is not a single concept in MassTransit that suggests you should use a separate bus for producers and consumers.

Thanks. I don't know why I thought it.
